# Let S be a finite linearly independent set of vectors in V, and let T be a subset of S. Show that T is a linearly independent set of vectors in V.

Tags: linear-algebra

I don't know where to start on this proof. I know that a linearly independent set is a set where c1v1+c2v2+⋯+cnvn=0 has no non-trivial solutions other than c1=c2=...=cn=0.

How can I use that to figure out this proof?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Just say that he who can do the more can do the less.

Answer (score 0):

Take any linear combination of elements of $T$ which turns out to be zero. Add rest of the elements of $S-T$ with coefficient 0. Now can you complete it?